# Why is my sys.prefix being set to '/usr'?

Tags: python, installation, sys

I'm trying to install python2.7 on linux from source on a system where I don't have admin rights.  There is a version installed in `/usr/bin` but I want my install to be completely independent of this.  I'm also testing builds with a newer gcc compiler so I want to avoid prebuilt packages like anaconda.

I downloaded python source and ran the following

```
./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR --exec-prefix=$INSTALL_DIR --enable-shared --enable-optimizations --enable-unicode=ucs4
make
make install
```

where `$INSTALL_DIR` is where I want my install to go.

The configure and build ran without error, however, when I run the built python executable

```
$INSTALL_DIR/bin/python
```

and check the search paths it is still using `/usr` as the prefix:

```
Python 2.7.13 (default, May 31 2017, 17:58:17) 
[GCC 7.1.1 20170503 (Red Hat 7.1.1-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys 
>>> sys.prefix
'/usr'
```

This means modules I install into `$INSTALL_DIR` aren't being found.  Also running `pip install XXX` doesn't do anything if the module is already installed in the `/usr` space.

I'd like to avoid using things like `$PYTHONPATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` so is there a way to set this up where `sys.prefix` and `sys.path` point to `$INSTALL_DIR` and know nothing about the system level install?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does the system use 2.7?

Comment: Yes,  the system has 2.7 and 3.6 installed in /usr/bin

Comment: Then that's why. Your REPL is using the system's library.

Comment: Okay,  I'm not sure what that is, but is there a way to not use the system library?

Comment: I don't see what part of this would actually install Python to `INSTALL_DIR` rather than the default install location.

Comment: After examining the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/getpath.c) that computes `sys.prefix`, I've found that while it contradicts the docs (particularly, the `--prefix` value is actually the final fallback, not an unconditional override), the actual behavior still shouldn't produce the results you describe. It sounds like there's something weird you're not telling us.

Comment: I added the `--prefix` to configure,  and thus after `make` the `make install` copies everything into $INSTALL_DIR`.  That part works as I expected.

Comment: But the Python build system doesn't look for an `INSTALL_DIR` variable for the install location. (I think it's `make DESTDIR=whatever install` to configure the install location.)

Comment: I tried setting DESTDIR when running make.  It just appends `INSTALL_DIR` to `DEST_DIR` and installs everything to `$DESTDIR/$INSTALL_DIR`.

Comment: ...oh, of course. `--prefix` and `--exec-prefix` don't just affect `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`; they actually configure where the relevant files are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Stop passing flags other than `prefix` to configre, and your python will give correct `sys.path` that stats with `$INSTALL_DIR`.

`$ ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_DIR`